# Automatically Hide/Unhide Column's based on value in row that is formula transposed from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Gday All

I am faced with a problem that I need all your help with. Please bear with me as I am relatively new to VBA coding and working through it.

I have a complicated issue that has been partially assisted with, however with the assistance I unsurfaced more issues.

In an individual worksheet `Accounts List`, the values in `B2:B45` are individually determined by a data validation list with options being yes or no. This yes or no answer is automatically transposed to a second spreadsheet being `Quarter 1` at `B4:AS4`. Note this is transposed by formula `=transpose()` and not VBA).

I need for the macro to recognise any updates in `B4:AS4` in `Quarter 1`, and hide any/all columns in the range that are NOT Yes.

The current code I am utilising is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In Range("B4:AS4")   
        Select Case cell.Value <> "Yes"
            Case False
                cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case True
                cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End Select
    Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

This code does work and is achieving the result I need, HOWEVER, it renders the spreadsheet VERY slow, in that each time I enter data or make a change ANYWHERE in `Quarter 1` the spreadsheet loads. I need this code to be both instantaneous and not lag, as a substantial amount of source data will be inputted manually.

Your help in advance is seriously appreciated!!

UPDATE: 
Due to difficulties, I am happy to click a Macro button on `Accounts list` to refresh `Quarter 1` if need be, semi-reduce the dynamic capability but a sacrifice I am happy to take.

Comment: So it is a value or a transposed formula?

Comment: Hi Mark, the row `B4:AS4` is a transposed formula. Well, its just transposing from the data validation list in `Accounts List`. No extra formula involved.

Comment: Try `Wroksheet_Change()` instead of `Worksheet_Calculate()`. You may need to specify a `Target` range in this instance though.

Comment: @Pascawali, you only need to code to run when you transpose from the first sheet, but it runs everytime you input data on the second sheet?

Comment: Thanks @Dean - how would this be achieved? (Sorry mate, newbie over here)

Comment: @AAA sorry, this question was so difficult to explain. That is correct, anytime I update anything in the field `B2:B4` on `Accounts List` I want the macro to run, otherwise I'd rather it doesn't so to not slow down `Quarter 1`.

Comment: @Pascawali it depends on when/ how you want the code to be called. Do you want this to be called when there has been a change in `Range("B4:AS4")` or do you want it to be called from another reference range/ cell?

Comment: @Pascawali, try the answer below.

Comment: @AAA responded to your answer mate
@Dean I would prefer a change in `Range("B4:AS4") however I am indifferent, if it reads from `'AccountsList! B2:B45` as the same result will be achieved

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B4:AS4")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell in Target.Cells
        With cell
            If .Value <> "Yes" Then
                .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
        End With
    Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working @AAA. Seems the worksheet doesn't pick up the change unless I click in and press enter within a cell thats changed.

Comment: You have to enter this code in the Sheet macro. It works for me, once the worksheet changes

Comment: is there a way of sharing the workbook with you so you can see? Its definitely not working for me and its in the right sheet?

Comment: see attached link mate. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxMPHQsHLGoBsqzbnBhKTS_zO8 

If you can have a look, that would be seriously appreciated!!